# URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a small website on Simple PHP with different folders/sections and files working with different Parameters.

i.e.

```
http://www.domain.com/folder1/file1.php?id1=66&id2=title_name

http://www.domain.com/folder1/file2.php?id1=85&id2=11&id3=title_name
```

MY TRY

```
RewriteRule  "^/dummy1/(.*)/(.*)/" "/folder1/file1.php?id1=$1&id2=$2"

RewriteRule  "^/dummy2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/" "/folder1/file2.php?id1=$1&id2=$2&id3=$3"
```

Please help me

Comment: How can i forward asp URL to php URL

http://www.siteurl.com/folder/filename.asp?query1=whatever1&query2=whatever2

to

http://www.siteurl.com/folder/filename.php?query1=whatever1&query2=whatever2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?dummy1/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /folder1/file1.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?dummy2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /folder1/file2.php?id1=$1&id2=$2&id3=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: How can i forward asp URL to php URL

http://www.siteurl.com/folder/filename.asp?query1=whatever1&query2=whatever2

to

http://www.siteurl.com/folder/filename.php?query1=whatever1&query2=whatever2

Comment: @M.s.khan Please ask a new question about this issue on .htaccess tag. We will help you.